# Broken colors when changing LookAndFeel Darcul=>Metal when application is running

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I have problem with changing application LookAndFeel from Darcula to Metal. When I'm changing from Metal=>Darcula or Metal<=>Nimbus everything is OK.

I use Darkula LookAndFeel from darcula-1.0.0.jar

On start:

```
BasicLookAndFeel darcula = new DarculaLaf();
try {
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(darcula);
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(windows.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

changing theme with this code:

```
try {
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(windows.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.pack();
```

After this some colors from Darkula LookAndFeel doesn't change to colors from Metal theme (as should) and result is Metal theme with dark background and menus.
How to fix it?

Comment: Do you change the Colors of any components manually by using setBackground(...) or setForeground(...).

Comment: No, I don't. 
I think a problem is somewhere in Darcula LookAndFeel, because when I change from Nimbus=>Metal or System=>Metal everything is ok, problem is only when I change Darcula=>Metal.
Is there any function which "reset" colours of LookAndFeel to default??

Comment: It depends how the LAF works. By design the LAF should set the Color using the `ColorUIResource` class. This tells Swing that when the LAF is changed the color should also be changed to the new LAF ColorUIResource. However, if you use, for example, component.setBackground( new Color(...) ), then when the LAF changes the background is not changed to match the new LAF because Swing assumes this is a custom color for all LAF. Look at [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) to see the defaults. Not sure if Darcula will be listed or not.

Comment: Thank you! This app halped me understand how does LAF works.
Temporary I made a solution which restarts app after change from Darcula=>Metal. Basic on this App example I think I will find final solution.